# Using the sortable() method and sending datain URL via jQuery

Tags: jquery

I two pieces of code which both work. Sadly, they don't work together.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#ui-sortable").live('hover', function() {

        **var string = '';
        var folders = $("[name^='note-behaviour-folder-add']");
        for(var x = 0; x < folders.length; x++){
            if ((folders[x].type === "checkbox") && (folders[x].checked)) {
                string = string.concat("&folders[]=" + folders[x].value);
            }
        }**

        $("#ui-sortable").sortable({
            update: function () {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: base_url + "behaviours/folders/jq_set_folder_behaviour_order",
                    data: "&note_id=" + $("#ui-sortable").data("note") + string
                });
            }
        });
    });
});
```

I need to know how I make the code marked in bold work within the context of the sortable() method.

Here, the code in bold is doing one thing (grabbing the values of checkboxes that have been sorted), but it's not reporting its data until after the fact, which means the sort data being sent is that prior to it being sorted.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Piece together your querystring inside the "update" callback. This currently most likely called before the sort takes place:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#ui-sortable").live('hover', function() {

        $("#ui-sortable").sortable({
            update: function () {
                var string = '';
                var folders = $("[name^='note-behaviour-folder-add']");
                for(var x = 0; x < folders.length; x++){
                   if ((folders[x].type === "checkbox") && (folders[x].checked)) {
                      string = string.concat("&folders[]=" + folders[x].value);
                   }
                }
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: base_url + "behaviours/folders/jq_set_folder_behaviour_order",
                    data: "&note_id=" + $("#ui-sortable").data("note") + string
                });
            }
        });
    });
});
```