# Drag and Drop / Sortable jQuery Ui Live - must be on, does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, events, live

In the past years I can use this code to work with live-events and drag&drop or sortable:

```
(function ($) {
   $.fn.liveSortable = function (opts) {
      this.live("mouseover", function() {
         if (!$(this).data("init")) {
            $(this).data("init", true).sortable(opts);
         }
      });
   };
}(jQuery));
```

But the "live" event is deprecated and does not work in newer jQuery versions. I tried to replace the live event with the on-event, but there are still error messages: `TypeError: n is undefined`

```
(function ($) {
    $.fn.liveSortable = function (opts) {
        $(document).on("mouseover",this, function () {                 
            if (!$(this).data("init")) {
                $(this).data("init", true).sortable(opts); 
            }
        });
    };
}(jQuery));
```

Do you have any suggestions what I can do instead?

---------------EDIT-----------------------------

I found another solution for me:

```
$(document).on("mouseover",".draggable", function () {

    $( ".draggable" ).draggable({opt}); 

});
```

Reference: [Using the sortable() method and sending datain URL via jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16768876/using-the-sortable-method-and-sending-datain-url-via-jquery?answertab=votes#tab-top)

Answer (score 0):

When do you get an error? Maybe something else goes wrong. I don't get any errors `here`: http://jsfiddle.net/TSv6Z/

Comment: But I try to use the "live" function. Cause the objects will be load via ajax. So the "on"-Event does not run. I tried it with:

$(document).on("mouseover",this, function () {

when I use your code, there is no error, but the sortable function does not work.